# Auto focus jQuery script not targeting next input field

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQyery code to auto focus on the next input field when the previous field has reached it `maxLength` value. However it won't place the focus on the next input field.

```
$(".input_focus input").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
     $(this).next('.input_focus input').focus();
    }
});
```

I guess that it might have something to do with the `.next` selector which should target the next sibling. But as for as I know the next `.input_focus input` is the sibling of the previous one.

This is the markup for a part of the form that I'm using:

```
<li id='field_8_8'  class='input_focus'>
    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_8_8' >My label<span class='gfield_required'>*</span></label>
    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_text'>
        <input name='input_8' id='input_8_8' type='text' value='' class='small' maxlength='4'  tabindex='5' placeholder='1234' aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </div>
</li>
<li id='field_8_10'  class='input_focus'>
    <label class='gfield_label' for='input_8_10' >My other label<span class='gfield_required'>*</span></label>
    <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_text'>
        <input name='input_10' id='input_8_10' type='text' value='' class='small' maxlength='2'  tabindex='6' placeholder='AB' aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
</div>
```

I'm not a jQuery expert by any means so I'm probably overlooking something. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `input` elements are not siblings and the selector you provide to `next()`, which is intended for sibling filtering, is actually trying to target the child of another parent element.

To fix this you need to amend the DOM traversal slightly. You can use `closest()` to get the parent `li`, then use `next()` to get its sibling `li`, then finally `find()` to target the `input`:

```js
$(".input_focus input").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).closest('li.input_focus').next('li.input_focus').find('input').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="field_8_8" class="input_focus">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_8_8">My label<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text">
      <input name="input_8" id="input_8_8" type="text" value="" class="small" maxlength="4" tabindex="5" placeholder="1234" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="field_8_10" class="input_focus">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_8_10">My other label<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text">
      <input name="input_10" id="input_8_10" type="text" value="" class="small" maxlength="2" tabindex="6" placeholder="AB" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply and the solution. It's working as intended now!